# Importing External Model Into ARToolKit Using Three.js

Tags: javascript, json, collada, artoolkit

I am trying to import an external model to one of the official ARToolKit projects using three.js. The project I'm using is the "pattern_threejs.html", and can be found here: https://github.com/artoolkit/jsartoolkit5

So far I have only managed to change the original sphere to display a cude instead when the marker is detected. The model I'm trying to import is an .fbx model, but I converted it into both Collada and JSON models using Blender. I tried several methods to import it, but everytime I try to do it, nothing appears when the marker is shown to the camera. 
Collada code:

```
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
            loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
            loader.load( 'pump.dae', function ( collada ) {
                var object = collada.scene;
                object.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
                object.position.set( 0, 0, 0.5
            } );

arController.loadMarker('Data/patt.hiro', function(markerId) {
            var markerRoot = arController.createThreeMarker(markerId);
            markerRoot.add(loader);
            arScene.scene.add(markerRoot);
        });
```

JSON code:

```
arController.loadMarker('Data/patt.hiro', function(markerId) {
        var markerRoot = arController.createThreeMarker(markerId);
        var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
        loader.load( 'pump.json', function ( geometry, materials ) {
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ) );
        markerRoot.add(loader);
});
        arScene.scene.add(markerRoot);
    });
```

Any suggestions? Would be a great help! Thanks!